# ElasticSearch clone BoolQueryBuilder object to another object by Value

Tags: elasticsearch, copy, deep-copy, pass-by-value

I have a BoolQueryBuilder object in Java 8:

`BoolQueryBuilder ogObject; // Having some clauses already`

And I want to deep copy ogObject to another object, say copyObject and add more clauses to the copy, leaving the original object unmodified.

How do I do this?

Doing

```
BoolQueryBuilder copyObject = new BoolQueryBuilder();
copyObject = ogObject;
```

copies it by reference.

Comment: have you found answer for this?